# Inheritance in Django: child class updates parent with empty fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models

I am creating a UserProfile for every user created with django.contrib.auth by extending the base abstract user and catching the signal when a new user is registered (I prefer having a separate table for the profiles):

```
class UserProfile(auth_models.User):
    objects = UserProfileManager()
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField()
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@django_dispatch.receiver(
    django_signals.post_save, sender=auth_models.User
)
def user_migrated(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if not created or raw:
        return
    if instance.pk != 1:
        return
    account_models.UserProfile.objects.create(
        user_ptr=instance,
        organization='The SATNet Network',
        country='US'
    )
```

The problem is that every time I create a user, the base user is first inserted correctly but the creation of the profile provokes Django to "update" the base user that has just created with empty values:

```
DEBUG (0.001) INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$15000$TacxtITENWvn$e6LbDUtE1XcAwz/Kfj6vNj40yQurEOcBCRJe6LrBTls=', '2015-06-02 18:48:32.826604+00:00', true, 'satnet_admin', '', '', 'satnet.calpoly@gmail.com', true, true, '2015-06-02 18:48:32.826604+00:00') RETURNING "auth_user"."id"; args=('pbkdf2_sha256$15000$TacxtITENWvn$e6LbDUtE1XcAwz/Kfj6vNj40yQurEOcBCRJe6LrBTls=', '2015-06-02 18:48:32.826604+00:00', True, 'satnet_admin', '', '', 'satnet.calpoly@gmail.com', True, True, '2015-06-02 18:48:32.826604+00:00')
DEBUG (0.001) UPDATE "auth_user" SET "password" = '', "last_login" = '2015-06-02 18:48:32.886904+00:00', "is_superuser" = false, "username" = '', "first_name" = '', "last_name" = '', "email" = '', "is_staff" = false, "is_active" = true, "date_joined" = '2015-06-02 18:48:32.886951+00:00' WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1; args=('', '2015-06-02 18:48:32.886904+00:00', False, '', '', '', '', False, True, '2015-06-02 18:48:32.886951+00:00', 1)
DEBUG (0.000) INSERT INTO "accounts_userprofile" ("user_ptr_id", "organization", "country", "is_verified", "blocked", "anonymous") VALUES (1, 'The SATNet Network', 'US', false, false, false); args=(1, 'The SATNet Network', 'US', False, False, False)
Superuser created successfully.
```

If I do not create the profile, then the user is correctly inserted since Django does not update the model:

```
DEBUG (0.001) INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") VALUES ('pbkdf2_sha256$15000$nxWaMTdYVVKO$MGWYHw/NXoEwCxBryK+bYOoqTYsO0DXgyqkBEQNxq/I=', '2015-06-02 18:53:54.716366+00:00', true, 'satnet_admin', '', '', 'satnet.calpoly@gmail.com', true, true, '2015-06-02 18:53:54.716366+00:00') RETURNING "auth_user"."id"; args=('pbkdf2_sha256$15000$nxWaMTdYVVKO$MGWYHw/NXoEwCxBryK+bYOoqTYsO0DXgyqkBEQNxq/I=', '2015-06-02 18:53:54.716366+00:00', True, 'satnet_admin', '', '', 'satnet.calpoly@gmail.com', True, True, '2015-06-02 18:53:54.716366+00:00')
Superuser created successfully.
```

What is the correct way to handle this? Does Django always update the models like that or am I missing something?

(**Environment**: Python 3.4.2 + Django 1.7.4 + PostgreSQL)

Comment: I see you are using a custom manager `UserProfileManager`. Did you implement your own `create` method?

Comment: @rojoca: no I did not implement the create method within my custom manager, but I did not expect Django to exhibit this behavior... is this the normal behavior in terms of inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are inheriting from `auth_models.User`. This is multi-table inheritance and isn't really appropriate for this situation. See the django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

Which basically say if you want to store profile data in a separate table there is no need to extend `auth_models.User`. Just create a model with a `OneToOneField` to `auth_models.User`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = UserProfileManager()
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField()
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth_models.User)
```

Comment: I know that there is several additional ways to deal with this problem, but what still confuses me is the way Django deals with the inheritance. What is the reason for updating the base model with empty fields after creating the child object if I am already providing a pointer to the parent that has already been created and initialized?

Comment: @Ricardo it's because when you call `create` it creates a "new" UserProfile model. The user_ptr you pass in just sets the `OneToOneField` on that new model. The new UserProfile model will not have any User properties set unless you do it explicitly. Once you save it those User properties are all set to empty.